# How to sort rows according to frequency in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, rows

I have a list in Excel and access to VBA. My list looks something like this:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       G   H
house                           
garden                          
flat    house           boat                
mirror  car                     
garden  house                       
garden  coat    boat                    
house   garden  flat    room    boat    mirror  car coat
```

I want to sort it such that the most frequent entries are shown at the left (ideally alphabetically, but not necessary).

I also have data left to column A (not shown here) that cannot be moved.

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H
        house                       
garden                          
        house   boat                    flat        
                        car                     mirror  
garden  house                       
garden          boat            coat            
garden  house   boat    car     coat    flat    mirror  room
```

Does anyone have an idea how to implement a solution in VBA? Any and all constructive feedback/critiquism is welcomed.

I tried with custom sort, sort by rows without success

Comment: I must be oblivious, check that, I must be ProfoundlyOblivious because I do not understand why you don't use a Pivot Table

Comment: In order to help it would be great if we could take a look at your existing attempts to achieve your goal. Stack Overflow is NOT a coding service. ;-)

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I'd like to see how you obtain the desired output from the provided input with a Pivot Table.  Can you provide some hints?  Tks.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Pivot example and instructions provided as an answer.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious OK for an analysis, but the output is not in the format that the OP requested.  I think to do that will require some complex VBA programming.

Comment: @Ron Sure my output doesn't match. I didn't study the data before making the comment and wrongly interpreted what OP was looking for. It seems to me that a VBA solution is just one of many possible solutions and likely the easiest one to create with the least amount of out of the box thinking.  Can you explain more about the data properties, the significance of the chosen output format, and importantly if there are any hidden constraints?  For example, the output model breaks if a single word repeats inside a row.  This can be exploited to facilitate a solution. What else can you tell us?

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious You'd have to ask the OP about the significance of the data output and any constraints he has not mentioned.  That is what he specified initially and he has not returned to clarify anything since. Including your excellent point about repeats in the same row. I also don't know what he means by `data left to column A …  that cannot be moved.`  I suppose if he shows us what he has tried, and where he has run into problems, we may be better able to assist him.

Comment: @ron LoL !! To repeat what I wrote in my first comment, "[...] I must be ProfoundlyOblivious because [...]" I managed to somehow convince myself you were the OP...  I posted my answer with the pivot because I thought it was you, as the OP, who wanted to see it.  I asked you about the data properties because I thought it was you, as the OP, that did not provide enough information for me provide the answer you seemed to want   I even thought it was an odd use of the third person when you referenced the output format as "the format the OP requested" because, well, I thought you were the OP.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious HaHa!  I, too, have occasionally mistaken a commenter for the OP, and responded in kind.  Glad to see I am not alone.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in response to your comment: Pivot table is created by clicking.

A few clicks to create a query from the source data.
A few clicks to unpivot the columns
Just a few more than a few clicks to create the pivot table.

[image: How I made the table]